# Dynamically Created Buttons don't update on DataSource being changed using WPF MVVM XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, controls, dynamic-programming

I am new to MVVM and XAML and I’ve run into a road block. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated! We are using WPF/MVVM and XAML to dynamically create buttons on a WrapPanel. The buttons appear as normal and are bound to an observable collection (RigDataSrceClass). (The observable collection is fed by a call to a SQL stored Proc and then updated with new button status (Background and Foreground colors) by a Subscription to a Pub/Sub.)

The data is correctly getting into the Collection but the buttons backgrounds/foregrounds do not update – they forever stay the original color. I need all the buttons to update with new Status values as the status is changed in the RigDataSrceClass.

I’ve tried about 8 different ways to get the button colors to update, including a Style Template on mouse over event (which only changes the font/foreground color and doesnt take updates from the datasource), cs code-behind to build and update the buttons (This works in non-MVVM but in MVVM the RigDataSrceClass is not available in the View), and endless amounts of binding of templates and controls, all with no effect what-so-ever. Plus these didn’t work:

```
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = new ContentControl(); //Wipes out my buttons!            

        RigButtonsClassControl.InvalidateArrange(); // No effect

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate); // No effect

        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); // No effect

    }
```

The xaml follows:

```
    <Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="RigButtonsClassControl" ItemsSource="{Binding RigDataSrceClass,     Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1"    >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

<Button Tag="{Binding Id}" x:Name="RigBtn" Content="{Binding RigContent, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" Click="Button_RefreshControl_Click" FontWeight="Bold" Width="33" MaxHeight="33" Margin="1" Background="{Binding RigStatus}" Foreground="{Binding RigStatusForeground}" />

                </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>           
    </ItemsControl>            
</Grid>
```

The View Model cs code follows:

```
public class RigsViewModel : ViewModelBase<IMainView>, IPublishing
{
    ISubscription _subscriptionProxy;
    string _endpoint = string.Empty;
    List<String> rigSubscribedList = new List<String>();
    String txtTopicName;

    private ObservableCollection<RigButtonDataModelClass> _ObservCollRigData = new ObservableCollection<RigButtonDataModelClass>();
    public ObservableCollection<RigButtonDataModelClass> RigDataSrceClass 
    { 
        get { return _ObservCollRigData; } 
    }
…
}

    public RigsViewModel()
        : base(new RigsWindow())
    {
        this.ws_context = new FlexViewWCF.EntitiesModelServiceClient();
        this.rigFilter = string.Empty;
        this.isFilteringActive = false;
        this.Status = string.Empty;

        _endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointAddress"];
        MakeProxy(_endpoint, this);
        txtTopicName = "R464RigStatus,R469RigStatus,R472RigStatus,R496RigStatus,R498RigStatus,R514RigStatus";
        OnSubscribe();
        this.RetrieveRigsToDisplay();

//            var vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
//           vm.Resources.Add(new Resource { Id = 1, Content = "Resource 1" });

        foreach (FlexViewWCF.CurrentRigCustomerDto dto in this.RigsToDisplay)
        {
            RigButtonDataModelClass rbdmc = new RigButtonDataModelClass();
            rbdmc.RigContent = dto.RigNumber;
            rbdmc.RigCommand = null;
            rbdmc.RigStatusForeground = "Black";
            rbdmc.RigStatus = "LightGray"; //dto.Status;
            RigDataSrceClass.Add(rbdmc);
        }
        //this.RigButtonsToDisplay = rigsToDisplay.
        //RigButtonsToDisplay = 
        //MakeRigButtons();
    }
```

And I update the data from the Subscription here: RigStatus is the new Background color and the Foreground is explicitly defined...

```
            lock (rigsToDisplay)
            {
                foreach (FlexViewWCF.CurrentRigCustomerDto cusRig in rigsToDisplay)
                {
                    if (cusRig.RigNumber == topicName.Substring(1, 3))
                    {
                        cusRig.Status = e.EventData.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                foreach (FlexView.ViewModels.RigButtonDataModelClass cusRig in RigDataSrceClass)
                {
                    if (cusRig.RigContent == topicName.Substring(1, 3))
                    {
                        if (e.EventData.ToString() == "Black")
                            cusRig.RigStatusForeground = "White";
                        else
                            cusRig.RigStatusForeground = "Black";
                        cusRig.RigStatus = e.EventData.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you and best regards!!!

Comment: Does `RigButtonDataModelClass` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No. It doesn't. Thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: That was the solution!!!  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you immensely!

Comment: Added below :), I know you already have it working but I also added an example as it may help other that come across the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `RigButtonDataModelClass` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

If not you will need to add it to your class and call `NotifiyPropertyuChanged` on the properties required, this will notify the `Xaml` that the binding value has changed and will update.

Quick Example:

```
public class RigButtonDataModelClass : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private int _myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { _myProperty = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyname = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```